# C++ pass list of function calls as parameters

Tags: c++, function, qt, templates, variadic-templates

I am currently setting up a unit test helper class which in Qt with C++11 which verifies that a signal was emitted during the test agnostic of its order, example:

```
void TestUtils::verifyVolumeAdjustment(const QSignalSpy &vol_spy, uint percent)
{
    for(QList<QVariant> vol_call_args : vol_spy){
        if(vol_call_args.at(0).toInt() == percent)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    QString err = QString("volume never set to %1").arg(QString::number(percent));
    QFAIL(err.toLocal8Bit().constData());
}
```

I have a good dozen of those functions all for checking if certain signals were emitted. Now I need to write tests where order is of importance. In those tests I would need to verify for example:

```
Volume set to 10
Volume set to 50
```

But exactly in that order. Now my question is if there is a way with variadic templates or something similar to pass a list of function calls to a function. I imagine the generalistic order checking function to be something like this:

```
void checkExecutionOrder(const QSignalSpy& spy, FunctionCallList call_list){
    
    for(int i = 0; i < call_list.length(), i++){
         QSignalSpy temp;
         temp.append(spy.at(i)); //create a temporary copy of that caught signal to ensure its the only thing validated
         call_list[i].call(temp, arguments); // call the function from the list with modified spy and remaining arguments
    }
}
```

Is there any nice way of doing this so I do not have to create a order sensitive test function for each function?

Comment: Why not to make it simpler? E.g. pass not a single value for percent, but a list instead, like: `verifyVolumeAdjustment(const QSignalSpy &vol_spy, const QList<uint>  &percents)`. In the body you check whether the signal's argument correspond to the percentage in the list.

Answer (score 1):

another option is using lambdas..
here is how:

1. define the method taking a list, vector of `std::functions`
2. inside the method do a for loop and call every function
3. to call the method pass a vector filled with lambdas to be called...

---

```
void myFooFunction(QVector<std::function<int(int)>>& myVec)
{
    for(auto& x:myVec)
    {
        x(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    QVector<std::function<int(int)>> x;
    auto f1 = [](int x){qDebug() << "x ++" << x; return x++;};
    auto f2 = [](int x){qDebug() << "x --" << x; return x--;};
    x.push_back(f1);
    x.push_back(f2);
    myFooFunction(x);
```

Comment: Undestand but this does not solve the problem that I need to write a dedicated function for each thing I want to check because there are functions taking one int, two ints and sometimes a lot of other stuff.

Comment: nop... just pushback the methods in the vector if you already have them defined....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::vector` and `std::function` to pass a list of functions with same signature to `checkExecutionOrder`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using FunctionCall = std::function< void(int,int) >;
using FunctionCallList = std::vector<FunctionCall>;

void checkExecutionOrder(FunctionCallList call_list){

    for (auto f : call_list) {    
         f(42,42);
    }
}

void foo(int x,int y){}

int main() {
    checkExecutionOrder( { foo,foo } );
}
```